# set current tab as active tab using Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have set of five tabs and they are working properly. When i refresh the page,currently active tab will get shifted to default state.
But I want to set it for current active state, even after I refresh. Please let me know where I am going wrong

Html code:

```
    <div class="container">
    <section ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="TabController as tab">
       <ul class="nav nav-pills">
            <li ng-class="{active:tab.isSet(1)}"><a href ng-click="tab.setTab(1)">Home</a></li>
            <li ng-class="{active:tab.isSet(2)}"><a href ng-click="tab.setTab(2)">Underwriting</a></li>
            <li ng-class="{active:tab.isSet(3)}"><a href ng-click="tab.setTab(3)">Operations</a></li>
        </ul>

        <div ng-show="tab.isSet(1)">
             <h4>Home</h4>
        </div>
        <div ng-show="tab.isSet(2)">
             <h4>Underwriting</h4>
        </div>
        <div ng-show="tab.isSet(3)">
             <h4>Operations</h4>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

Js:

```
    (function () {
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

    app.controller('TabController', function () {
        this.tab = 1;  ---> Here I am failing to apply the logic.

        this.setTab = function (tabId) {
            this.tab = tabId;
        };

        this.isSet = function (tabId) {
            return this.tab === tabId;
        };
    });
})();
```

working demo : http://jsfiddle.net/fwoxdjsu/

Comment: You need to store active tab somewhere(like local storage/ server). On page refresh read the tab data and set it.

Comment: Use web storage 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API

And check for storage if value is set previously

Comment: localstorage is working bu it is bad way.for this purpose you can use angular router or ui-router

Answer (score 2):

Store the tab index in localstorage and on page refresh set it again. As index comes in string from local storage convert to number.

```
this.tab = +localStorage.getItem('tabIndex') || 1;
this.setTab = function (tabId) {
  this.tab = tabId;
  localStorage.setItem('tabIndex', tabId);
};
```

Here is [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fwoxdjsu/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Updated Js

```
(function () {
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

    app.controller('TabController', function () {
        if(typeof(localStorage.currentTab)=="undefined")
            this.tab = 1;
        else 
            this.tab = parseInt(localStorage.currentTab);

        this.setTab = function (tabId) {
                localStorage.currentTab=tabId;
            this.tab = tabId;
        };
        this.isSet = function (tabId) {
            return this.tab === tabId;
        };
    });
})();
```